# How to use posh-git-bash in oh-my-zsh?

Tags: git, bash, shell

I can use the posh-git-bash in normal bash shell, but I can't use it under oh-my-zsh.

First of all, I follow github project [posh-git-sh](https://github.com/lyze/posh-git-sh) to create ~/git-prompt.sh, and add the following scripts to the bottom of file ~/.bashrc

```
source ~/git-prompt.sh
PROMPT_COMMAND='__posh_git_ps1 "\u@\h:\w" "\\\$ ";'$PROMPT_COMMAND
```

reopen the terminal, and go to a git project folder, all the git prompts are correct and as I expected. e.g.

```
Orion@Orions-machine-1:~/Source/MyProjects/deploy_tools [master ≡ +0 ~1 -0 | +1 ~0 -0]$
```

Then, I follow the github project [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) to install zsh and oh-my-zsh. I choose the 'crcandy' theme, and add the scripts to the bottom of file ~/.zshrc.

But it always uses the format defined in theme 'crcandy', just show a '*' in prompt.

```
Orion@Orions-machine-1 [10:25:57] [~/Source/MyProjects/deploy_tools] [master *]
```

The file ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/crcandy.zsh-theme content:

```
PROMPT=$'
%{$fg_bold[green]%}%n@%m %{$fg[blue]%}%D{[%I:%M:%S]} %{$reset_color%}%{$fg[white]%}[%~]%{$reset_color%} $(git_prompt_info)\
%{$fg[blue]%}->%{$fg_bold[blue]%} %#%{$reset_color%} '

ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_PREFIX="%{$fg[green]%}["
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_SUFFIX="]%{$reset_color%}"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_DIRTY=" %{$fg[red]%}*%{$fg[green]%}"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_CLEAN=""
```

Anybody could give me help, and make them work together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Issue #14](https://github.com/lyze/posh-git-sh/issues/14):

> [I examined the git prompt plugin for `oh-my-zsh`, and it seems that
>   the git prompt plugin sets
>   `RPROMPT`](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/plugins/git-prompt/git-prompt.plugin.zsh#L92),
>   presumably to avoid stepping on the `PROMPT` variable set by the
>   theme.
>
> I refactored a little bit, so in your `.zshrc`, you can easily get a
>   posh git status indicator.
>
> ```
> . posh-git-sh/git-prompt.sh
> RPROMPT='$(__posh_git_echo)'
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The way that I achieved this is certainly not the way that is recommended, but for me it was simple and un-intrusive to the rest of the way that zsh operates.

Quite simply I placed the git-prompt.sh file from [here](https://github.com/lyze/posh-git-sh) into my /usr/local/bin directory so that its in my path with my other local tools

I then edited the zsh theme file that I want to use (for me thats apple, its simple and uncluttered) and called the __posh_git_echo function

In my case I added the line

```
. /usr/local/bin/git-prompt.sh
```

and then edited the PROMPT line to ..

```
PROMPT='%{$fg[magenta]%}$(toon)%{$reset_color%} %~/ %{$reset_color%}$(__posh_git_echo)%{$reset_color%}'
```

I hope this helps someone else, I am pretty sure it will be useful to future Tim. (terrible memory for this stuff)

The downside is that its then only active in this theme, but for me thats no big deal, if I want to change themes i'll edit the theme file to suit.